# flot chart options not working with metronic

Tags: flot

So, I downloaded a theme from metronic. I took out all of the features that I don't need, then I put in a portlet for a Flot graph and pasted in data and options that I used with the graph when it was on another script. For some reason, the Label axes don't show up and the times are wrong on the x axis. Does anyone know why this isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

I believe Metronic lacks the flot-axislabels plugin by default.

To get axis labels working:

- navigate to the plugin directory `cd assets/global/plugins/flot/`
- download the plugin `curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/markrcote/flot-axislabels/master/jquery.flot.axislabels.js`
- add script to html `<script src="assets/global/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.axislabels.js"></script>`

The following config should display "Hello World Label" on the X axis:

`xaxis: {
    tickColor: "#eee",
    ticks: 11,
    tickDecimals: 0,
    axisLabel : "Hello World Label",
    axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
    axisLabelFontSizePixels: 12,
    axisLabelFontFamily: 'Verdana, Arial',
    axisLabelPadding: 5,
    labelWidth: 200,
    labelHeight: 20,
    reserveSpace: true
},`